# IoT device networks and border router in Cooja

Tags: iot, router, contiki, cooja

I am new to Cooja Contiki. I have a network simulation comprising 5 web sense motes and one border router. I want to figure out how to ensure that the entire communication among sense motes **only occur via border router**. Could someone advise regarding this?
This is the [expected simulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7fLs.png)

Comment: You have to say more...
RPL is constructing the DODAG automatically, by discovering the "best" route towards the sink (border router). If it evaluates a neighbor as the best parent, it will connect through this node.
Now, if you want all nodes to connect directly to the sink, you can always make sure that they don't "see" any other node (outside wireless coverage), or they are close enough to the sink, so they will not "prefer" a neighbor as a parent. The parent choice is done via the objective function (OF), which estimates the parents based on traffic, signal, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Is there any solution that involves modifying the code(in router or web sense) so that the above restrictions could be implemented?

Comment: there is an implementation of such an algorithm (choosing neighbors based on their color. Look here https://github.com/SWNRG/rpl_link_coloring, here https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/8832178. You can easily change/adapt the algorithm to choose for example only parents with red color...

Comment: Thanks for the references. I have a small doubt though. I want a communication like mote1 -> router -> mote2.  If I ensure that mote1 -> router takes place, I will need them to have the same color, same for router -> mote2. So, basically mote1 and mote2 would be having the same color, won't they communicate among themselves defeating the whole purpose? Please advise.

Comment: Be careful: The communication in RPL is basically UPWARDS. I.e., it is m1-->sink<--m2. Communication between m1<-->m2 is not RPL's priority, since it is "many-to-one". Especially if the nodes don't have direct wireless communication, and even worst, if they don't have a common ancestor (they belong to different branches), they don't communicate, unless you involve the sink to do so.